# Express Route & Socket io

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Ok so I had my socket io connection sending information to the frontend and the client is also able to respond, thereby saving the returned data.

However it doesn't make sense to have socket io initiated in the `server.js` file when its only use takes place in the `'/user/home'` route.

so my question is how do I use socket io in a route if http server is initiated in `server.js` without calling a new instance of http server?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have it configured:

I have an io.js library that handles socket io stuff:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();
io.path('/socket');
client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("Redis successfully connected");
});
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('a user connected: '+ socket.handshake.query.uid_bsp);
    console.log('socket id: '+socket.id);
  //clients.uid_bsp=socket.id;
  //console.log('a user added: ');  
  client.set(socket.handshake.query.uid_bsp,socket.id);
});

io.notifyTransfer = function (uid_bsp,data){
    client.get(uid_bsp,function(err,socketid){
            console.log('notifying: '+socketid);
            io.to(socketid).emit('update', data);
    });
};



module.exports = io;
```

And in server.js I have this library required, and attached to server:

```
var httpserver = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('./src/utils/io.js');
...
var server = httpserver.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });

io.attach(server);
```

So in my routes (which are separate js files like rest, front,....) , I can use notifyTransfer method just requiring io library.

Hope this helps